# 404 when clicking on Last Activity

Tags: support, 404-not-found

I was surfing around both Super User (and Meta SE for testing), and noticed if you click the link for "Last activity", it comes up with a 404 error.

[image]
Clicking that link shows the lovely 404 page:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had an add on that made me look like I was the Google Bot for testing some websites last week. I forgot to turn it off. Once it was off, SE would complete the redirect.